# How to package a Maven Java application for Debian?

Tags: debian, java, packaging, application, maven

I am trying to package a Java application that is built with Maven.

I created the `debian/` folder with `mh_make` and I have been reading/watching the tutorials:

- https://wiki.debian.org/Java/Packaging/Maven
- https://wiki.debian.org/Java/MavenRepoHelper
- https://wiki.debian.org/Java/Packaging
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p767bS_8C_o
- And more which I am forgetting now

The project structure is as follows:

- parent POM
- my_app submodule
- my_app_lib submodule (used exclusively by my_app)
- shared_lib submodule (used by my_app but may also be needed by other apps)

I am trying to create two deb packages, which will:

- Install my_app and its lib in `/usr/share/my-app` (package 1)
- Install the shared lib in `/usr/share/java` (package 2)

I am at the point where I have created part of package 1:

- Installed my app's main jar in `/usr/share/my-app/my-app.jar` and its dependency lib jar `/usr/share/my-app/lib/my-lib.jar` (via `my-app.install`)
- Created a launch script `/usr/share/my-app/bin/my-app` and symlinked it to `/usr/bin` (via `my-app.install` and `my-app.links`)

In the POM I also set the main class and instructed Maven to add a classpath in the jar's manifest.

**My questions:**

1. How do I force the `mh_*` scripts to **not** install the `my_app` or `my_app_lib` artifacts and POMs in the `/usr/share/maven-repo` or `/usr/share/java` dirs? My poms file for reference:

```bash
# The setup below does not work - my_app and my_app_lib are installed in /usr/share/maven-repo
pom.xml --ignore-pom
my_app/pom.xml --has-package-version --ignore-pom --no-usj-versionless --dest-jar=/usr/share/my_app/my_app.jar
my_app_lib/pom.xml --has-package-version --ignore-pom
lshared_lib/pom.xml --ignore
```

2. How do I set the `lib/` prefix to the classpath generated by Maven? I have currently solved this by adding a `<classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>` in the POM but I would prefer to set it as part of the packaging process as it is a Debian-specific change.
3. How do I link the shared lib to my app? Currently, I am thinking:

- Install it as usual with another `<package>.poms`
- Add dependency on the lib binary package to the my-app binary package
- Add a symlink between `/usr/share/my-app/lib/shared-lib.jar` and `/usr/share/java/shared-lib.jar` in `my-app.links`

  Would that work? Can I build a second binary package from the same source package? Is this the correct way of doing this?